# File writing behavior varies depending on OS in R?

Tags: r

I use R (2.15.1) scripts to pass variables to an externally compiled library function. During computation, the function (NOT the R script) creates a number of files which are written to and updated after each iteration of my algorithm.

Now the strange part. Running on MacOS (Mountain Lion), the files are created and updated as expected. I can also view them (tail -f) during computation. On Windows and Linux the files are not written until the function completes. I prefer to monitor the output files during the computation.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior (and a way to change it in Windows/Linux)?
Seems like a great way to waste memory...

Thanks.

Comment: The writes to the files are likely buffered.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `flush` function in R.  Just flush the file handle after each iteration.